# How to read a specific section of App.config file in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I need to read/fetch a particular section of app.config file,values under ...  can be read using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XYZ"], however how do I read/fetch values under  ... For e.g. I have to read value corresponding to "File" in below shown code

```
 <log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender"  type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
  <param name="File" value="C:\Logs\"/>
</log4net>
```

Comment: So what code did you try Yourself and What is Not working ?

Comment: I have no clue how to go about accessing custom tags apart from <appSettings> tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 <log4net>
 <appender key="rolltest" name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" />
 <param name="File" value="C:\Logs\"/>
 </log4net>
```

you need to add key to your tag

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("log4net") as NameValueCollection;
var value = section["rolltest"];
```

Comment: getting an error at var value = section["rolltest"]; as Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Aniruddha - Did you add `key="rolltest"` in your tag? Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The web.config and app.config are normal XML files, meaning that .NET classes for reading xml files can be used to get the values you are looking for.

```
XElement something = XElement.Load("app.config location");
```

Then query using LINQ or get specific element.